# How to use MapInfo PEN patterns in MapServer?

Tags: symbology, mapinfo, mapserver

I want to use `tab` files in MapServer WMS. My layer config:

```
 LAYER
   NAME Background
   TYPE LINE
   STATUS DEFAULT
   CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
   CONNECTION "D:\dev\Mapserver\ms4w\apps\example\tab\road.tab"
   STYLEITEM "AUTO"
   PROCESSING "GETSHAPE_STYLE_ITEMS=all"
   CLASS
     NAME "road"
   END
END # Layer
```

In MapInfo `road.tab` looks like:

[image]

But my WMS shows just default black lines. After I had added file with symbology to `MAP` section:

```
SYMBOLSET      "D:\dev\Mapserver\ms4w\apps\etc\symbols_mapinfo.txt"
```

I found this file in Mapserver docs , and it's contains mapinfo symbols like this:

```
# 67 - tent
Symbol
Name 'mapinfo-sym-57'
Type VECTOR
Filled TRUE
Points
0 1
.5 0
1 1
.75 1
.5 .5
.25 1
0 1
END
END
```

in `ogrinfo` I find that my layer use this symbology:

```
PEN(w:1px,c:#000000,id:"mapinfo-pen-73,ogr-pen-0")
```

But what next? How can I declare this style in symbology file?

Comment: What's the content of your symbols_mapinfo.txt file

Comment: @nmtoken i added part of file in question.